# Where do i find System.Windows.Media ? The Media is not exist

Tags: c#

I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AviFile;
using ScreenShotDemo;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.
```

In my new class but in the bottom system.Windows.
There is no Media

Im using visual c# pro 2012 and .net 4.5
Tried to add it as reference looked for it in .net and in COM but it's not there.

The reason i need it is that in my code i have PixelFormat and it's not exist:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(currentScreen.Bounds.Width,
currentScreen.Bounds.Height,
PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

PixelFormat not exist.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually using anything from `System.Windows.Media` here.

Comment: It looks like you want to mix WPF (`System.Windows.Media`) and WinForms (`System.Drawing`) APIs. Are you sure you want to do that? The rest of your code makes me suspect you don't want to use `System.Windows.Media` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add System.Drawing.Imaging to your using statements.

You can usually easily find what you need to include by right clicking on the item in question and choosing "Resolve"

Comment: Thankyouuuuu, 3 years using vs and never knew that it is so easy to resolve a namespace +1 for the tip

Answer (score 3):

System.Windows.Media requires reference to PresentationCore.dll and

Pixelformat requires references to System.Drawing.dll.

See reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx).

Comment: Bizarre... but yes, adding a reference to "PresentationCore.dll" solved this problem for me.  Merci b'coup.

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this answer to, like me, spent hours trying to find a `using System.Windows.Media`, and can't get the BitmapImage. Just use the `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging`. It works just fine.