# Namespace System.Media does not exit

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp

Trying to use `System.Media.SoundPlayer` (C#, VS 2015 UWP), however getting the error:

> The type of namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace System.

Included reference to `PresentationCore.dll`, which allows the statement `using System.Windows.Media` but not `System.Media`.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086966/where-do-i-find-system-windows-media-the-media-is-not-exist

Comment: @sheppe No, that's about the namespace that is available. System.Media.SoundPlayer isn't available in UWP as far as I know.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen gotcha. I overlooked the UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Media` namespace is not available in UWP applications so you can't use `SoundPlayer`. For playing sounds or other media you can use [`MediaElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187272.aspx)